# Authenticate ECR via Docker Remote API

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-api, aws-ecr

I need to login to my `AWS ECR` repository so it can pull whatever images it needs by using API. I need to translate what `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --registry-ids <registry_id>` command does using Docker API.

For example --

1. **[Solved]** API call needs to be made to AWS in order to get login credentials for docker

   - API call for this will give me `base64encoded` string which has `username` and `password`
2. **How to use those `AWS creds` in a docker login API (by using [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/SystemAuth)) call (equivalent 
   to `docker login -u AWS -p <password> <server_address>`)??**

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do -

1. Get the output from AWS API
2. Process the AWS API output to get the base64encoded string
3. Run docker login API call with the base64encoded string

If you have access to bash -

```
#!/bin/bash

login_command=$(aws ecr get-login | sed 's/-e none//g' | sed 's/  */ /g')

if (echo "$login_command" | grep -q -E '^docker login -u AWS -p')
then
  $login_command;
fi
```

You could translate the logic into other languages as you wish.

Comment: After decoding `AWS`'s response I was trying this:
```curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -d '{"username":"AWS","serveraddress":"<server_address>", "password": "<password>"}' -X POST http://localhost/auth```
But not getting any response. Do you havre any idea about this!!

Comment: Decoded response is like: `AWS:<long_string....>`.
So my `username` is `AWS` and `password` is `<long_string....>`.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your original question, by docker API call you mean with a curl instead of the "docker login -u AWS -p <password>' command?

Comment: Yes, sir.  See this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/SystemAuth